# How to improve this data-visualisation?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a `d3.js` plot that I want to improve it but I can't figure out how to do it!

**This is my plot:**

[image]

**Mainly I am trying to change axis and add a little legend so I can get something like this (with x and y zeros centered in the plot ):**

[image]

**This is how I define `x` and `y` axis in my d3.js/JavaScript code**

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })]).range([padding, w - padding]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; }), d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })]).range([h - padding, padding]);

//  Create axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(5);
            //Define Y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").ticks(5);

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("#mydiv").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);


svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")").call(xAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)").call(yAxis);
```

Thanks in advance:

Comment: To "zoom out" a little bit, multiply the result of `d3.max` by a number greater than 1 and multiply the result of `d3.min` by a number less than 1, e.g. 1.05 and 0.95, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide your actual dataset I can give you more exact code for your case, without it the best we can really do is give you examples from the docs.

How to create a legend:

```
   // draw legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  // draw legend colored rectangles
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  // draw legend text
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d;})
```

How to hardcode max/min on your axes:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,6]).range([h - padding, padding]);
```

How to add gridlines:

```
var yAxisGrid = yAxis
  .tickSize(width, 0)
  .tickFormat("")
  .orient("right")

var xAxisGrid = xAxis
  .tickSize(-height, 0)
  .tickFormat("")
  .orient("top")

svg.append("g")
  .classed('y', true)
  .classed('axis', true)
  .call(yAxisGrid)

svg.append("g")
  .classed('x', true)
  .classed('axis', true)
  .call(xAxisGrid)
```